# Menu Item Select Problems

Tags: android, view

This is my NavagatorView code,

```
<item

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="Main"
    android:id="@+id/Main"

    />

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_wc_black_24dp"
    android:title="Matched"
    android:id="@+id/Matched"
    />
```

This is my click register code,

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Main:
                //newGame();
                return true;
            case R.id.Matched:
                displayInfoDialogView();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I want it so when I click "Matched" the displayInfoDialogView(); runs.
Now when I run it nothing happens.

Comment: your NavagatorView code, is in which folder?

Comment: its a regular bottombar

Answer (score 0):

add this code below in your onCreateView method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Comment: OnCreateView? I dont have that.